# Is there any way to create tables at run time using room ?

Tags: android, android-room

Is there any way to create tables at runtime using room using existing schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since room use `@Entity` annotation to generate tables, I don't think you can create tables at runtime simply using Room.

But room is just a wrapper for Sqlite, you can fall back to Sqlite and SQL and then manipulate database.

`RoomDatabase` has lots of helpers. For example, `yourRoomDatabase.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase()` returns a traditional writable database. Just like old days.